# Apache solr and eclipse taking up huge amounts of memory

Tags: hardware, kubuntu, apache2, java, eclipse

I have this pc with kubuntu and it gets really slow when I run programs like eclipse or talend. I know those two are memory hogs but I have 6gb ddr3 (it does not say in the list but it's ddr3) and sometimes it's not all occupied and I the computer really slows down.

Also I think there is a problem with apache solr and kubuntu. When I run apache solr, apache uses 5gb of ram. In ubuntu server (with less memory and less cpu power) the same solr queries only make apache take up a few hundred mbs.

Here is the hardware list given by lshw, please tell me if any component is incompatibel with ubuntu: http://pastebin.ca/1995800 (couldn't post it here because it was huge)

Thanks

EDIT:

java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

I am using this java version and it's the same as in my ubuntu server machine which runs apache and solr without a problem.

Comment: it's likely not a hardware issue, but a software issue.

Comment: Are you running 64 bit?

Comment: @dv3500ea: Yes it's 64bit

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with Java, all the programs you've got issues with are Java projects.

Consider installing a different JVM, if icetea isn't working try sun-jvm. If that isn't doing the trick then try one of the other javavms.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: I have updated the question to include my java version

Comment: And is this the exact same version as you have on your desktop?

Comment: Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using system monitor (gnome) to see which processes are hogging the cpu and then renice them to give them a lower priority.  Also, if you use the console I would recomment htop since it's very intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0):

To debug Java memory issue, use JVisualVM to inspect your Java program. There is a great memory profiling tool which can be used to discover what uses lots of memory.
JVisualVM is packaged in Ubuntu, and available from the partner repository.